# Restricting decimal places

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using either:

```
CAST( SUM(a.fieldmissed) AS decimal(18,8)) / SUM(a.fieldtotal) *100 AS [Deliveries Missed]
```

or

```
SUM(a.fieldmissed)*100.0 / SUM(a.fieldtotal) AS [Deliveries Missed]
```

to work out % values. However, is there a way I can restrict the output to two decimal places? Not essential but would be handy to know.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),value)` to convert the value to 2 decimal
or
use `ROUND(value,2)` to round the value to 2 decimal.

Comment: May i know the reason for down vote?